# praxis + -cracy =?

Tags: greek, derivation

We have from ancient Greek the suffix [`-cracy`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cracy).

> From Ancient Greek -κρατία (-kratía), from κράτος (krátos, “power”).
>
> Suffix: rule (in the sense of governing).

We also get from the Greeks the word [praxis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praxis#Etymology):

> From Ancient Greek πρᾶξις (prâxis, “action, activity, practice”).

and here only the etymology is relevant; not the common ways in which the term is used today.

The intended meaning of this derived term would be, essentially:

> leadership by those who do.

**If we were to combine the two terms, to form a new derived term, how would we spell it?**

The naive attempt (and perhaps also the correct one?) would lead us to: `praxicracy`.

But I can also imagine: `practocracy`? So, if we were to try and keep a decent sense of Greek grammar, and (less) a decent sense of English tradition, what would we come up with?

Comment: Editing aside: the intended meaning isn't parenthesised but paramount.

Comment: Where would to "rule by action" even apply?

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps in a volunteer organization -- the people who do the work get to make the decisions.

Comment: If you're coining a new word, you get to decide how it's formed, unless it's within the scope of an organization with specific naming guidelines.

Comment: But if you're coining a new word, it's off topic here. To be on topic, the question should be about the mechanics of the existing -cracy words, or something precise like that.

Comment: 'Coining a new word' is usually a contradiction in terms, as many D-I-Y attempts do not garner enough support to achieve wordness. There is a mistaken belief that splicing established components guarantees a new word will result. But productuvity is gradable.  ELU does not consider candidates that are not established.

Comment: Wouldn't [meritocracy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meritocracy) very nearly satisfy this meaning?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It seems more like it's redundant than a contradiction.

Comment: @Barmar It's used by many who think that as soon as a white-space-bounded letter string appears on other people's screens, that is by definition a word. The existence of 'non-word' as a word would argue otherwise (and realistic definitions of 'word' involve a reasonable degree of currency). I use the term 'coined' when a candidate has been accepted into the lexicon, back-dated if possible to its first public appearance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think we're entering some murky philosophical waters here. I would say "He coined the word X, but it didn't catch on."

Comment: Do you need Greek? If not, try [*do-ocracy*](https://communitywiki.org/wiki/DoOcracy), maybe. Also seen in the wild: *doacracy*.

Comment: @Barmar But I regard 'word' and 'didn't catch on' as mutually exclusive. 'Failed candidate.'