# Word for nonce antonyms formed by reversing idioms

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms, neologisms, humor

Someone recently used "on-limits" to describe something that was allowed, i.e. not "off-limits." The same person subsequently described unplugging something as "plugging it out," i.e. the opposite of "plugging it in." To be clear, this person is a native English speaker and is engaging in word play.

I found these to be rather charming creations, but are obviously not proper or common usage. I am curious if this sort of thing is a known phenomenon and if there is a word to describe it.

This concept rings similar to a malaphor, i.e. a mixture of two aphorisms ("we'll burn that bridge when we come to it"), and it sort of resembles an unpaired word, wherein the removal of a negative prefix does not result in an antonym (ambiguate is not an antonym of disambiguate).

Would love to hear any thoughts on this.

Comment: They just look like a play on word to me.

Comment: My favorite is the marvelous [**Recombobulation Area**](https://onmilwaukee.com/articles/recombobulationsigns) sign at the Milwaukee Mitchell International Airport.

Comment: I've heard younger speakers use "plug it out" without realising it's 'wrong'… Give it half a generation, it'll be 'right'.

Comment: Woops: play on words, with an s.

Comment: It sounds like a first cousin to a malapropism.

Comment: I am glad to learn the word malaphor; it describes a phrase a friend once spoke impromptu: "unleash the floodgates!"

Comment: Ooh, a mixed metaphor in three words.

Comment: Sometimes these neologisms catch on for their utility: unbold, unfriend, diss, anti-vax sext.

Comment: @YosefBaskin our PE teacher would say "Spread out in a bunch" and "Double up into threes"!

Comment: @WeatherVane Gottaluvit.

Comment: *Catachresis*, maybe? [*...the practice of adapting the nearest available term to describe something for which no actual (i.e., proper) term exists*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catachresis-1689826). If deliberate, it is done for rhetorical effect — like, duh, what can be plugged in can surely be plugged out.

Comment: “Faux antonym” sounds more like a term whose meaning is seemingly opposite, but actually is not. (Like “open” and “closed” in topology.)

Comment: *stark dressed* and similar...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There is nothing in English that is “not proper”

There can be things that are not common (e.g. obsequious or morrow), inappropriate for the context (e.g. street language in Parliament or vice-versa), or new coinages, but they are perfectly [cromulent](https://thehill.com/blogs/in-the-know/4228895-merriam-webster-adds-word-first-used-on-the-simpsons-to-dictionary/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CFans%20of%20%27The%20Simpsons%27,%2DWebster.com%20dictionary.%E2%80%9D). It’s perfectly proper for your friend to expand the language with new words. After all:

[image: all words are made up]

### We are looking at the [lost positive](https://viviennelingard.net/2018/05/03/the-mysterious-case-of-the-lost-positive/)

This is a broad church.

A “true” [lost positive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7TfjCIbtng) is a word that once existed in English but has fallen into disuse except in the negative form. So once, with appropriate gorm and feckfullness, it would still not have been evitable that we could eff the ineffable. Because, it’s ineffable, it would need to be effable to be effed, obviously.

There are also words whose definitions have changed; the positive still exists but it doesn’t mean the opposite of the negative anymore. We can appoint someone to high office, but while we can disappoint them, it doesn’t mean we sacked them, but it did once.

Related are those where the words themselves have changed so they no longer form an obvious pair. Like unkempt/combed, or inept/aptitude.

Then, there are the imports; words that have a pair in another language but English only ever imported one of them.

Then again, there are the ones that aren’t really opposites. Disgruntled is not the opposite of the disused word gruntled meaning to complain; here, “dis” is used as an intensifier not a negator - a disgruntled person is someone who complains *a lot*. But we now have, thanks to P G Wodehouse, the modern form of gruntled meaning to be satisfied. A found positive for a word that was actually a negative.

Which brings us to your friend’s back-creations. These are also lost positives in the sense that they were absent and have now been coined. My favourite is ‘combulated’ as the opposite of the word deliberately made up in the 19th century as a play on both  ‘discomfort’ and ‘discompose’ - if you transit through Milwaukee, be sure to stop off in their [Recombobulation Area](https://onmilwaukee.com/articles/recombobulationsigns).

Comment: +1 for the proper use of a meme

Comment: An answer with a great deal of aplomb

Comment: If you believe @EdwinAshworth's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/617109/praxis-cracy?noredirect=1#comment1568146_617109), a word isn't actually coined unless it actually becomes a part of the lexicon.

Comment: @Barmar a word is coined the instant it is created - whether it lives or dies after that is irrelevant

Comment: @DaleM That's what I said!

Comment: (Worth noting that although word play is fun, and it may be that nothing in English is improper, many things may not be understood — so it's worth bearing your audience in mind.)

Comment: @Barmar: Is it enough to be minted, or need it be circulated?

Comment: @Drew I guess we can consider an analogy between coins and casino chips. Coins are legal tender almost anywhere, casino chips are only accepted at that specific casino. We don't consider chips to be coined.